Will Not Boot After New Screen Install (Blank White Screen)
I have replaced a damaged screen on my son's HP 350 G1 laptop. I now get a blank white screen at boot. I have to press ESC button repeatedly at boot, then F9 to select the operating system to boot into Lubuntu 24.04 LTS. I did temporarily reconnected the original screen which still boots correctly. When in Lubuntu I reset the monitor settings and saved them, but same problem when booting after shutdown. Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted) is ticked in software sources and I have installed updates.

Edited /etc/default/grub. Changed  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
Using advanced options for Ubuntu from the grub menu, I was able to update grub. After this the laptop now boots properly, even the next day.
